# Как отрендерить переменные из соседнего файла конфигурации?

Tags: python, jinja2, yaml

Есть файл api.yml содержащий конфиг вида:

```
config/application.properties:
  server.port: 6081
  system.default.lang: rus
  api.pdd.url: "http://{{ stage['PDD'] }}"
  api.policy.alias: "integration"
  api.order.url: "http://{{ stage['Order'] }}
  api.foo.url: "http://{{ stage['FOO'] }}
```

Так же рядом лежит stage.yml содержащий ключ и значения `stage`:

```
default_node:
  Order: '172.16.100.40:8811'
  PDD: '172.16.100.41:8090'
  FOO: '10.100.0.11:3165'
```

Моя задача распарсить api.yml и превратить его в properties-конфиг.
Проблема заключается в том, что не могу подтянуть значения `{{ stage['value'] }}`
Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
stream = yaml.load(open('api.yml'))
result={}
result.update(stream['config/application.properties'])
context= yaml.load(open('stage.yml'))
stage={}
stage.update(context['default_node'])
text = '{% for items in result | dictsort(true)%}  {{ items[0] }} = {{ items[1] }} {%endfor%}'

template = Template(text)
properti = (template.render(result=result, stage=stage))
```

На выходе получаю вот это:

```
server.port = 6081
system.default.lang = rus
api.pdd.url = http://{{ stage['PDD'] }}
api.policy.alias = integration
api.order.url = http://{{ stage['Order'] }}
api.foo.url = http://{{ stage['FOO'] }}
```

А хотелось бы получить это:

```
server.port = 6081
system.default.lang = rus
api.pdd.url = 172.16.100.41:8090
api.policy.alias = "integration"
api.order.url = 172.16.100.40:8811
api.foo.url = 10.100.0.11:3165
```

Comment: выведите что вы посылаете на рендер? я так понимаю `result`

Comment: @Eugene Dennis  Привет я пытаюсь отправить на рендер и result и stage " properti = (template.render(result=result, stage=stage))" , точнее я пытаюсь-это сделать.И не знаю, как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте передать следующую структуру данных:

```
stage = [{ "Order": '172.16.100.40:8811', 
           "PDD": '172.16.100.41:8090', 
           "FOO": '10.100.0.11:3165'}]
```

И использовать шаблон для списка словарей:

```
{% for dict_item in stage %}
   api.order.url = http://{{ dict_item["Order"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Если jinja не обязательна посоветовал вам бы использовать python-форматирование. Я так когда-то отказался от jinja.

Вам понадобиться 4 файла (config.yml), первый собственно то, что хотим получить:

```
server.port = 6081
system.default.lang = rus
api.pdd.url = http://{PDD_value} 
api.policy.alias = integration
api.order.url = http://{Order_value}
api.foo.url = http://{FOO_value}
```

Второй файл (input.py) для значений переменных:

```
values = {
   "PDD_value": "111", 
   "Order_value": "2222", 
   "FOO_value": "333"
}
```

Третий для связи входного и выходного (reader.py):

```
from input import values

def read(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        t = f.read()
    return t

util = { "files": [
   {"file": "config.yml",
   "content": read_file(".../config.yml").format(**values)},
]
}
```

Ну и последний для запуска (run.py):

```
import reader
for item in reader.util["files"]:
    with open(item["file"], 'w') as f:
        f.write(item["content"])
        print 'Success'
```

Всё в одной папке стартуете run.py. После запуска перепишется файл `config.yml` - с проставленными входными из `input`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению такой вариант "{% for dict_item in stage %}api.order.url = http://{{ dict_item["Order"] }}"  мне не совсем подходит, хоть я и указал 3 переменных, на самом деле их может быть более 500-ста и также я не могу знать заранее, какие из них конкретно будут в файле,так как файлы конфигов будут разные.Я попробую ваш вариант, без jinja, но всё же хотелось реализовать через неё.Это всё часть большого и уже итак перегруженного скрипта и не хотелось бы нагружать, его дополнительной логикой, если существует вариант сделать - это через jinja.